# Error: "The query returned more data than will fit on a worksheet"

Tags: error-handling, popup, excel-2010, excel-external-data

When I refresh my workbook, the following message pop-ups :
 "The query returned more data than will fit on a worksheet"? I have around 30 Sheets which have connections to external queries. How to check from which sheet this error is coming and how to solve it?

THanks!

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In the External Data Properties for each data connection where it says:  "If the number of rows in the data range changes upon refresh" try the setting "Insert entire rows for new data, clear unused cells."

Comment: This is the first time I get this error message, and this totally fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If the file containing the data began life as an XLS file, it may not hold more than ~65K records in one tab, even after saving as XLSX format. It seems that this limitation carries over. I had to create a new XLSX file to get around this.

Comment: This solved the issue for me. The other answer regarding External Data Properties is incorrect if you have an XLS/MS Excel 97-2003 file.